# Using script inside a div (in a react .js file) throws error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a js file which is part of a larger website using react.
I have a class and inside the render & return I have a div which displays a popup form, inside that I wanted to add javascript as I've done previously, but the first line of script is giving the error [ts] Expression Expected.

Code example:

```
<div className='popup_inner'>
{
//the script, fails first line on var with [ts] Expression Expected
var necc = $('example')[0]; 
//more code 

}
</div>
```

Later in the code I do the same thing which works fine

```
<div className='example2'>
<button onClick = {script variable}> Save </button>
```

I've done many google searches, and used `<script>` instead of `{}` but it didn't make any difference. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Did you import `$` from `JQuery`?

Comment: Can you tag this with jQuery because this seems not to be reactjs.  You are not allowed to make assignments in html elements in reactjs.  If you have a render prop function in react on custom elements you can declare variables inside the function but this is not allowed.

Comment: Take a look at my answer.  Also, you should try to use `document.querySelector()` since it can accomplish what you are showing and alleviates bloat in your code from having jQuery imported.

Comment: You cannot put JS statements inside JSX. If you want to declare variables, do it at the start of `render()`, not inside the JSX you return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely a ReactJs issue.  So, you cannot make any declarations in a react return statement.

a React call looks like this:

```
const ReactElement = () => {
  var dataInside = 'Something Something'
  return <div>{dataInside}</div>
}
```

See how the variable is declared above the return statement.

You are trying to return while declaring variables where `dataInside` is located.  What you are doing returns nothing, move it up before the return statement.  If you really want to mix jQuery with React you could do something like this

```
const ReactElement = () => {

  var necc = $('example'); 

  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: necc.html()}}>
}
```

Comment: The variable assignment should be done outside the return which can then be  reference in the JSX inside the return after yes. +1

Answer (score 1):

As @HarishSoni mentioned, you probably didn't import `$` from jQuery.

If you only need to assign a variable inside this div, I would recommend replacing your jQuery variable assignment here with a pure JavaScript variable assignment instead like this:

```
<div className='popup_inner'>
{
var necc = document.querySelector('example'); // you dont need to add [0] since querySelector returns the first element by default
}
</div>
```

---

**Update:** @Moosecouture's answer is the correct way to do this. The variable assignment should be done within the `render` but outside the `return` like this:

```
class SomeReactClassName extends React.Component {
  render(){
    var necc = document.querySelector('example');
    return (
      <div className='popup_inner'>
        <p>The variable above is {necc}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense, unfortunately it doesnt change anything, the error is still there

Comment: @Moosecouture's answer is the correct way to do this. The variable should be created within the render but outside return as shown in his answer.

Comment: @Uciebila Check the updated code to see how you should go about it within a class component.